# Avoid copying of argument when inserting elements into a vector

Tags: c++

The question is simple and short, but I did not manage to find a good solution yet: **How should I insert objects into a `std::vector`?**

Clearly, I can do `vec.push_back(MyObject(param1, param2, param3))`. But is this a reasonable solution, considering the call-by-value and therefore copying of `MyObject`? (In case the object is large or not copyable.)

I also wonder whether it is save to return a pointer on the newly constructed and inserted object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11 you can construct objects in place with `vector::emplace_back()`.